# Spark data not partioned while reading hive views

Tags: apache-spark-sql, hive

I’m trying read a hive view which is internally 3 hive external tables by spark sql for processing . The data is not partioned properly . All the data lies in the single partion . My hive view partioned only.

But I’m trying to read the original all three hive tables and tried join in spark sql it is properly partioned.

Any solutions ?
Thanks